# How to calculate sum of events between two dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where I need to count the number of events between two dates for each person.

In the below DataFrame, for each type A date I need to count the number of type B dates until the previous type A date for each person. There are no restrictions on how many type A and B dates there are for each person.

I want to avoid for-loops as they are slow.

DataFrame

```
Person Date     Type 
1      01/01/19 A  
1      01/05/19 B 
1      02/01/19 A
1      03/01/19 A
2      01/01/19 A
2      01/07/19 B
2      01/25/19 B
2      02/01/19 A
2      02/05/19 B
2      04/01/19 A
3      03/01/19 A
3      04/01/19 A
```

Desired Output

```
Person Date   Count
1      2/1/19 1
1      3/1/19 0
2      2/2/19 2
2      4/1/19 1
3      4/1/19 0
```

Comment: This is a great example of a place where you may need an external loop because you need to maintain state. 

Everyone will tell you, "Don't use for-loops because that's anti-pandas" but then you end up with stuff like this where the problem becomes difficult/impossible to solve because it's inherently stateful. How many rows do you have? Are you sure this isn't premature optimization?

Comment: I have about 12k rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without a `for`-loop. My solution requires a bunch of pre-processing though, and the final result isn't *exactly* like your desired output, but very close (and correct). For clarity's sake I've split it up into multiple steps - you could condense these down into fewer if you're into that sort of thing.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Making dummy data
d = {"Person":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],
     "Date":["01/01/19", "01/05/19", "02/01/19", "03/01/19", "01/01/19", "01/07/19", "01/25/19", 
             "02/01/19", "02/05/19", "04/01/19", "03/01/19", "04/01/19"],
     "Type":["A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["isB"] = df["Type"] == "B"
df["step1"] = df["isB"].astype(int).diff().fillna(0)
df["step2"] = df["step1"]
df["step2"][df["isB"]] = 1
df["step3"] = (df["step2"] == -1).cumsum()
grouped = df.groupby(["Person", "step3"])

result = pd.DataFrame({"Date":grouped.last()["Date"], "Count":grouped["isB"].sum()})
result.index = result.index.droplevel(1)
result = result.reset_index()

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
   Person      Date  Count
0       1  01/05/19    1.0
1       1  03/01/19    0.0
2       2  01/25/19    2.0
3       2  02/05/19    1.0
4       2  04/01/19    0.0
5       3  04/01/19    0.0
```

The two differences to your desired output are:

- There is an extra entry for person 2. This is due to the way I'm grouping, it results in the last "A" entry for person 2 being its own group, thus producing a count of 0.
- The dates displayed are of the last "B" entry, not the next first "A" entry. Not sure if this is worth bothering to fix, so I didn't.

I hope this helps, or at least provides inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks molybdenum42 for the insight. I didn't know about diff. This gave me an idea about using diff on the index filtered on Type A. I couldn't find out how to do this on the index itself so I copied it to another column. The dataframe is already in order by Person and Date, but I included it in the code below.

```
d = {"Person":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],
     "Date":["01/01/19", "01/05/19", "02/01/19", "03/01/19", "01/01/19", "01/07/19", "01/25/19", 
             "02/01/19", "02/05/19", "04/01/19", "03/01/19", "04/01/19"],
     "Type":["A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Person', 'Date'])
df_sorted.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_sorted['_index'] = df_sorted.index.values

group_a = df_sorted[df_sorted.Type == 'A'].groupby('Person')
df_sorted['Count'] = group_a['_index'].diff()-1
df_sorted[df_sorted.Count.notna()]

Person  Date    Type    _index  Count
1   02/01/19    A       2       1.0
1   03/01/19    A       3       0.0
2   02/01/19    A       7       2.0
2   04/01/19    A       9       1.0
3   04/01/19    A       11      0.0
```